# Does Entity Autocomplete has database leak?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

Lately in one of our prod database the "key_value" table became 2.4GB large.
When I took a closer look I could see that there is around 200 000 records in it, and 90% of them are `entity_autocomplete` collection. Then I searched the entity reference module where does it operate with the `keyValue` service and I found the following:

```
// \Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete:129
   $selection_settings = isset($element['#selection_settings']) ? $element['#selection_settings'] : [];
    $data = serialize($selection_settings) . $element['#target_type'] . $element['#selection_handler'];
    $selection_settings_key = Crypt::hmacBase64($data, Settings::getHashSalt());

    $key_value_storage = \Drupal::keyValue('entity_autocomplete');
    if (!$key_value_storage->has($selection_settings_key)) {
      $key_value_storage->set($selection_settings_key, $selection_settings);
    }
```

The `$selection_settings` may contain the host entity as well (it's because of the self reference feature). This means based on the code: whenever you have a new entity or the entity updated your `$selection_settings_key` will always be different. Also it's added to the key-value table without expiration date which will end up as a permanent out of date record (after the entity changed / field config anyhow) in your key-value table. Also because it's serializing the whole entity the record itself can be quite big (talking about 10-12 KB).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known bug:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2826826#comment-12376276

> As mentioned in IRC, the problem with adding even just the entity
>   id/UUID to those options is that we create entity * entity reference
>   key value entries.
>
> The key is based on the hash, so an ID/UUID in there results in a
>   different hash for every entity. At the very least, we would need to
>   switch to an expirable key value store, so we can clean them up but it
>   is still a non-trivial overhead that is being added.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2826826#comment-12644652

Seems to fix it for me:

```
    // Don't serialise the entity, it will be added explicitly afterwards.
if (isset($selection_settings['entity']) && ($selection_settings['entity'] instanceof EntityInterface)) {
  $element['#autocomplete_query_parameters']['host_entity_type'] = $selection_settings['entity']->getEntityTypeId();
  $element['#autocomplete_query_parameters']['host_entity_id'] = $selection_settings['entity']->id();
  unset($selection_settings['entity']);
}
```